# Telerik Kendo Grid or Telerik RadGrid: offer many columns (scalability)

Tags: asp.net, telerik, kendo-grid, radgrid

What you'Il often find when using a dynamically expandeable grid like Teleriks RadGrid or Kendo's Grid is that the more columns you offer to the user the more data needs to pulled in and the more heavier the query becomes. This happens partially because the grids don't pass the selected columns to the data source.

For example, if we have a Product with many components, locations, and other properties, we prefer not to pull in the properties we don't need.

In what way can the problem of needing to pull in so many data be mitigated? Is it possible to pass the selected columns to the data source? Or can the fields be loaded afterwards via a seperate AJAX call?

I know RadGrid and Kendo Grid are two completely different technologies but I'm interested in the answer to both. I'm sure someone must have seen the same issue with these types of grids.

Answer (score 1):

One way to mitigate the problem is to apply server-side paging to the grid - that way only the data required will go over the wire. Generally the problem with data volume in grids is the rows rather than the columns.

Also, make sure the data source is being queried efficiently, particularly where you are joining data from different tables in your data source.

Comment: The problem is that column selection is entirely done on the client. No selected columns are passed to the data source.